# Quisiera saber como puedo poner unos LABELS al lado de unos INPUTS

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy aprendiendo de html con bootstrap y quisiera saber de que forma puedo hacer que me queden los labels al lado izquierdo de unos inputs
Asi es como lo tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi como lo quiero dejar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

osea "Nombre completo" al lado izquierdo

este es mi codigo:

CSS:

```
HTML: 

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Fromulario1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
    </head>
      
      
    <body>
      
    <center>
    <header>
      <h1>Formulario Solicitud de Beca</h1>
    </header>
    </center>
      
    <section>
      <div class="contenedor">
        <p>Bienvenido a nuestro sistema de Solicitud de Becas online. Para ser tenido en cuenta para una beca en
    nuestra universidad, debes completar la solicitud de beca online antes del 1 de Marzo de 2021. Aplicar
    online no tiene cargo y te permite enviar toda la documentación respaldatoria necesaria a través de
    nuestro Formulario de Solicitud de Beca aquí debajo.</p>
      </div>
      
      <h2>Datos personales</h2>
      
      <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group two-fields">
            <label>Nombre completo:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="fecha">Fecha :</label>
      <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha"><br><br>
      <div>
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mail">mail:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Adicional como hago para que el input de fecha me quede del mismo tamaño del contenedor, que se autoajuste, agradezco cualquier ayuda no doy en como hacer eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo utilizas la versión 3 de  Bootstrap, puede actualizar a la v.5
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/

Ejemplo de form horizontal  :

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="col-form-label-sm">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="colFormLabel" placeholder="col-form-label">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="colFormLabelLg" placeholder="col-form-label-lg">
  </div>
</div>
```

espero te ayude!

Comment: exacto era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo Bootstrap V3, podes implementarlo así:

```css
    .input-group-addon {
      background-color: transparent!important;
      border: none!important;
    }
    .input-group .form-control {
      border-radius: 4px!important;
    }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>Fromulario1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          
        </head>
          
          
        <body>
          
        <center>
        <header>
          <h1>Formulario Solicitud de Beca</h1>
        </header>
        </center>
          
        <section>
          <div class="contenedor">
            <p>Bienvenido a nuestro sistema de Solicitud de Becas online. Para ser tenido en cuenta para una beca en
        nuestra universidad, debes completar la solicitud de beca online antes del 1 de Marzo de 2021. Aplicar
        online no tiene cargo y te permite enviar toda la documentación respaldatoria necesaria a través de
        nuestro Formulario de Solicitud de Beca aquí debajo.</p>
          </div>
          
          <h2>Datos personales</h2>
          
          <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group two-fields">
                <label>Nombre completo:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Apellido</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <label for="fecha">Fecha :</label>
          <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha"><br><br>
          <div>
          <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mail">mail:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```